# How to remove a text that has a certain number of digits?

Tags: notepad++

I have this line:

```
John | Doe | 4th Street, Block 7 | +1 | Confirmed | 8745219966
```

I'm trying to setup a form for a wedding invitation, it is formatted as:

```
First Name | Last Name | Invitation Address | +1 or No | Invitation Status | Phone Number
```

I would like to remove all lines that has a 9-digit number. How can I do this in Notepad++?

Also, how do I edit it so I can have something like this?

```
John | Doe | 4th Street, Block 7 | +1 | Confirmed
```

I want to remove: `| 8745219966`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this Regular Expression. **Find/Replace** to get a sophisticated dialogue including a drop down for regular expressions and multi line search/replace.

```
([|])*([0-9]*\s+)*[0-9]*$
```

This Regular Expression will find all the continuous integer even if it is 3 digit or bigger.

Comment: Thank you very much Mohit Shrivastava. Is there a way to save this search in Notepad++? Because there's no way I can memorize this.

Comment: You can save a file with regex and their usability terms in one file so that next time you can search it in your file itself. I have no idea how to save this search term.